# Command 'key' is not defined when running craft install

Tags: python, pip, masonite

I'm trying to create a new Masonite project and I'm getting this error when running `$ craft install`

> Command "Key" is not defined

I had installed the `masonite-cli` using pip not pip3

Comment: Can you share some more info...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens for several reasons. Either the project was not fully installed properly

- Did you run `craft install`?

Or your craft version is installed globally incorrectly

- Did you use pip (with points to Python 2.7) and then create a virtual environment using Python 3?

To fix this typically requires uninstalling craft (`pip uninstall masonite-cli`) globally and either reinstalling with `pip3` or installing it only within your virtual environment.

try running something like:

```
$ pip uninstall masonite-cli
$ pip3 install masonite-cli
```

And then activating your virtual environment and checking if it works OR

```
$ pip uninstall masonite-cli
$ source venv/bin/activate # activate virtual environment
(venv)$ pip install masonite-cli # inside your virtual environment
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I had installed the masonite-cli using pip not pip3!

Comment: How would you know if you're on the venv already?